# How to capture hidden <div>

Tags: java, html, selenium

From below HTML:

```html
<div class="wpsc_buy_button_container group">
  <br>
  <div class="input-button-buy">
    <br>
      <span><input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button"></span>
    <br>
  <div class="alert error">
     <br>
      <p>Please select product options before adding to cart</p>
     <br>
      <span>&nbsp;</span>
     <br>
</div>
```

When clicked on Add To Cart button following alert error will show and will be hidden. **How to capture the `<div>` alert addtocart as this is hidden by default?**

```html
<div>
  <br>
 <div class="alert addtocart" style="display: none;">
  <br>
   <p>Item has been added to your cart!</p>
  <br>
   <span>&nbsp;</span> 
  <br>
 </div>
  <!--close input-button-buy-->
 <div class="wpsc_loading_animation" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <br>
   <img title="Loading" alt="Loading" src="http://store.demoqa.com/wp-content/themes/mio/images/ajax-loader.gif">
 </div>
  <!--close wpsc_loading_animation-->
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: You can wait for the element to be visible and use get Text method to capture the text of it.

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: What prog language you using? Create a custom wait on the visibility of the div. Inside the apply() method of the WebDriverWait class retrieve the text of the div.

Comment: I'm coding in Java.

Comment: private static void CaptureAlert(WebDriver driver, int cart_count)
{
   WebDriverWait cart_wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  cart_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.className(".alert.addtocart"), String.valueOf(cart_count)));

Comment: System.out.println("Alert " + cart_count + ' ' + driver.findElement(By.className(".alert.addtocart")).getText());
}

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try  using `JavascriptExecutor`

use this code:

```
WebElement element_hide= driver.findElement(By.xpath("wpsc_loading_animation");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element_hide);
```

Comment: I'm coding in Java, I don't see above method

Comment: WebDriverWait cart_wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); cart_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementL‌​ocated(By.className(‌​".alert.addtocart"), String.valueOf(cart_count))

Comment: I used above code but throwing error
`waiting for text ('Item has been added to your cart!') to be present in element found by By.className: .alert.addtocart (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)`

Comment: Let me check and test